# error C2061: syntax error : identifier, but header file is already included

Tags: c++, syntax-error, identifier

I have a big game engine to compile and it worked fine until I did some crazy adjustments. The compiler somehow cannot reconize my mean Game object and produce `error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Game'`, and it seems no matter what file I compile the error always points to a file called `GameDataLoader.h` even there is absolutely no connection with this two files. Usually I think it is an inclusion problem but the fact is I have `Game.h` included in every .h file necessary, right after the inclusion of stdafx.h and I have `#pragama once` on top of it. I thought about circular inclusion problem but the `#pragma once` should take care of that. Plus this inclusion directives works fine until I changed some file name and other messy stuff. I cleaned the entire solution and tried to rebuild it but still no luck (using VS2012).
I don't know if showing the code will help, but here is the code for `gameDataLoader.h`. This isn't a file I wrote but it should work properly.

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Game\Game.h" // Game.h included

class GameDataLoader
{
public:
    GameDataLoader(){} 
    ~GameDataLoader(){}

void GameDataLoader::loadGameProperties( Game *game, map<wstring, wstring> *properties, wstring gameInitFile);

    virtual void loadGame(Game *game, wstring gameInitFile) = 0;
    virtual void loadGUI(Game *game, wstring guiInitFile) = 0;
    virtual void loadWorld(Game *game, wstring levelInitFile) = 0;
};
```

And I had errors exactly on those 4 lines with Game object. What could possibly be the problem?
Double inclusion? Circular inclusion? Or did not include something and somewhere else?

Comment: Don't just rely on `#pragma once`. Use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: @StoryTeller I have almost 100 files and they all used `#pragma once`, and it worked before. It's kind of unpracticle for me to change all the hundred files

Comment: Nevertheless, I had to say my piece about something the may reduce portability.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most likely, `Game.h` is including `GameDataLoader.h`, either directly or indirectly, creating a circular dependency; but you forgot to show us `Game.h`, so I can't be sure of that.

If that is the case, then `#pragma once` (or the equivalent include guard) will mean that one of the headers will be included before the other, and declarations from the second won't be available to the first. It won't magically include both of them before each other, since that is impossible.

Luckily, `GameDataLoader.h` doesn't need the full definition of `Game`, since it only deals with pointers to it. So you can remove the inclusion of `Game.h` and just declare `class Game;` instead.

Comment: I do have `class GameDataLoader;` forward declaration in `Game.h`, but that inclusion is necessary. And it turns out I have instantiated a `dataLoader` class in `Game.cpp` but that has been flag as an error since there are virtual functions in my .h file. By deleting it I get rid of that problem. Although there are some other similar issue poped up and I believe it's caused by similar problems and I didn't notice. Thanks!

Comment: Still I have one more question. This time the problem happened to be in `Game.cpp` but why is that affecting `GameDataLoader.h`? Since it only includes .h file. What do you possibly think might be the cause?

Comment: @ryf9059: If the problem is a circular inclusion, then you'll get the error in any file that includes either header. Although without the missing information about which files include which others, I can't do much more than guess what the problem might be.

Comment: You are the best! God, I hate Visual Studio for having such obscenely misguiding error notices. They have a page just for this error on the web, and no hint of such a cause even there. This was supposed to be their job, yet, and luckily, @MikeSeymour came to our rescue!